# Как добавить веденные значения в список?

Tags: python, циклы, списки

Имеется список. Есть переменная var, она является его диапазоном. С помощью цикла в списке создаются определенное кол-во элементов, зависимое от веденного значения var, и этим элементам нужно ввести значение. А как веденные значения добавить в список и затем вывести его?

```
var = int(input())

l = list(range(1, var + 1))

for x in l:
    x = int(input('['+ str(x) + ']: '))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то можно вот так:

```
a = [int(input()) for _ in range(int(input()))]
print(a)
```

ну или если совсем коротко:

```
print([int(input()) for _ in range(int(input()))])
```

Answer (score 3):

Существует функция `list.append()` 
Она добавляет элемент в конец списка.
Попробуй использовать ее.

Answer (score 2):

В вашем варианте в списке `l` и так будут все введенные числа. А распечатать их можно просто:

```
print(l)
```